# Cursor disappearing in winforms (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem with the cursor in my winforms app. When I press a button on the form, the cursor disappeares for a short period of time (1-3 sec.)

Any ideas? Could this be caused by a backround worker interfering with cursor = cursors.waitcursor call?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have a process that is running and 'freezing' the UI during that timeframe.  Using BackgroundWorker and cursor = cursors.waitcursor might be causing the issue.